# Cleaning up text? "The Beatles" to "Beatles, The"

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I'm working on website with lyrics from all kind of bands, much like Lyrics.com I guess. What I have right now is a page that echo's the name of the band, the title of the song and the text itself from the database. I would like to properly categorize this.

Take for example "Strawberry Fields Forever" by "The Beatles".

I would like to categorize this as "B"  as in "Beatles". And on `Example.com/b/` list every band that starts with the letter B. My question:

- The name of the band is The Beatles but "The" should be dropped. How would I do this? Making two columns in the database `author` and `authour-clean` would be way to much work.

Also, my URL currently is:
`example.com/lyrics.php?id=1`
 . I would like this to look like `example.com/b/beatles/strawberry-fields-forever`. From Googling I understand this can be done with .htacces? Is my database designed correctly for this right now? This is what it looks like ATM:

*(darn, cant post images -- here is plain text)*

```
id (int10)
title (varchar255)
author (varchar255)
lyrics (text)
```

I was thinking I need another column, e.g. `category` and for this example the value `b` (as in Beatles) to more easly list all bands starting with B, and to make sure the htaccess thing is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can accomplish goal number one. The best way would either be a preg_replace like Trendee suggests or even breaking the string into an array and then searching for instances of words you'd like to replace. The array version is cool because you can easily shuffle stuff around.

As for the second goal, you're looking at mod_rewrite. What is happening is that when you go to your url example.com/b/beatles/strawberry-fields-forever, you'll have a rewrite rule that says "treat each / as if it were part of a query string" and you define what each one is. So in reality, your url is:

?category=b&band=beatles&song=strawberry-fields-forever.

There are [tons of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite%20clean%20urls) on how to do this

Answer (score 4):

> - The name of the band is The Beatles but "The" should be dropped. How would I do this? Making two columns in the database `author` and `authour-clean` would be way to much work.

While this might appear to be more initial work, you'd find that it is a solution which would require less work in the long run.

If you were to pre-index the author's by how they are supposed to be searched then you can let SQL do all of the work for you when it comes to returning results.

Storing the data properly in the database is always preferred over doing complex processing (over and over) when pulling the data out.  Space is a lot cheaper than processing power, not to mention how much faster this would end up being in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be of use.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php